# Invalid Keyword when working with CSV on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
def c():
    csvfile = 'example.csv'
    with open(csvfile, 'r') as fin, open('new_'+csvfile, 'w') as fout:
        reader = csv.reader(fin, newline='', lineterminator='\n')
        writer = csv.writer(fout, newline='', lineterminator='\n')
        if you_have_headers:
            writer.writerow(next(reader) + [new_heading])
        for row, val in zip(reader, data):
            writer.writerow(row + [data])
```

Above is some code that I have used to create a column for a CSV file. I keep getting the following error

```
TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) the only references to `newline=''` is when opening the file.

Comment: so you would want the `newline=''` in the `with open(csvfile,'r', newline='') .. `

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `newline` argument should be included within the `open` function, not the csv `reader` and `writer` functions.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) for examples.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the help. It worked fine. I have one extra question. I essentially have 2 more copies of this that add 2 extra columns excluding this one. When I run the code, they later ones override the previous one. They all create a column in the same place. How do I make one create a column after the other (so they create a column on the next one over)?

Comment: @NasifRob what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You're welcome @NasifRob. Please create a new question for the other problems though, it isn't very easy to help out using the comment section only

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this error , open the file in 'wb' mode instead of 'w' mode.
This will eliminate the need for newline = "",
Look below the the corrected code.

```
csvfile = 'example.csv'
with open(csvfile, 'r') as fin, open('new_'+csvfile, 'wb') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, newline='', lineterminator='\n')
    writer = csv.writer(fout, lineterminator='\n')
    if you_have_headers:
        writer.writerow(next(reader) + [new_heading])
    for row, val in zip(reader, data):
        writer.writerow(row + [data])
```